# What do you call cuts on a loaf?

Tags: word-request

I wonder what do you call these cuts?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique is called **scoring**, but the individual cuts are just called **cuts** or **slashes**.

> Start at the top of the round (the side farthest from you) and begin making diagonal slashes in series from top to bottom. I like to add a gentle curve as the cuts progress from top to bottom; this curved set looks nice when the loaf expands up and outward in the oven. Then, repeat for the other side of the stalk where each cut matches its pair to the side.

from ["Bread scoring techniques", King Arthur Baking](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/blog/2017/10/20/bread-scoring-techniques)